# Movie Clip node vs Image node - why two separate node types?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Are the [*Movie Clip*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/movie_clip.html) and [*Image*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/image.html) nodes meant for distinct tasks? If so what are those distinct tasks, i.e. when would you choose one over the other?

[ I mean for a reason more fundamental than that you don't want to convert your movie into an image sequence. ]

It looks very much as if the functionality of both could be combined into a single node so I'm wondering what purpose is served by having the two distinct nodes?

I can use an image sequence with both, if I do then they both look fairly interchangeable for basic cases:

[image: move clip and image nodes]

However, it's clear there are differences. Most interesting for me, is that the *Image* node allows you to specify a *Color Space* whereas the *Movie Clip* node does not. This seems an odd omission for the *Movie Clip* node.

But the *Movie Clip* node has various output's that the *Image* node doesn't, i.e. offset, scale and angle (but *Image* has depth).

I'm wondering if I'm missing something? Is there a good reason for the distinctions rather than having a node that can both deal with 1 to n images (like *Image*) and handle them irrespective of how they're wrapped up (as an image sequence or as a movie like *Movie Clip* can).

PS I know I've ignored sound as an aspect of movie clips and just focused on the image side of things.

Comment: "Movie Clip" is usually a part of "Motion Tracking" workflow and its data sockets are useless without it (except alpha). Color space and other input options could be changed inside tracking options.

Comment: OK - that makes things clearer. I hadn't been aware of the tight binding between the _Movie Clip_ node and the tracking setup. I see now that if I go to the _Motion Tracking_ workspace and change the _Color Space_ setting in the _Footage_ tab then I see this reflected in the _Movie Clip_ node in the _Compositing_ workspace. This linkage between the node and settings made elsewhere hadn't been obvious to me.